# Should an array be ordered server side or client side

Tags: java, node.js, architecture, software-design

This is a general and technology free question. But if this has different answers for different technologies, please focus on cassandra as No SQL DB, node.js as server side technology, Java as client side technology, and JSON to describe the array of objects.

What is the best practise to order an array of objects, in server side or client side?

Comment: Java as client side?

Comment: @SimoEndre yes, Android to be more specific

Comment: I would say "maybe" - how well does your server-side scale, how much performance cost is associated with server side sorting, and how slow is it to sort on client side (would the client notice)? Client devices are "free" computer power for you, server-side costs you resources. Also for "paged" data sets you have to sort on the server anyway to work out which page you are on.

Answer (score 4):

General rule of thumb is not to trust the client side.

However, life is not black and white I believe, but it is shades of grey (not necessarily 50 shades of grey. hahahaha. Joke aside). I think it depends on data size and how you use it. If data does not change dynamically and if it not too large to bog down the client's system, I vote it is OK to do it on the client side. Specially if user wants to sort the data on various criteria as she sees fit.

But if data is dynamic or if it is too large, it is safer to do it on the server side.

Comment: If you can't trust it to sort properly, you can't trust it to do anything else properly either. +1 for "shades of grey" though.

Comment: @AndyBrown I used to think more or less the same. But Javascript sort of proved us wrong. ;) And thank you for +1

Answer (score 1):

If it is related to DB then ofcourse server side, because you can include in the query the "order by" frase with "asc" or "desc" and the query will sort it for you, and avoid all the problems with sorting on the client side to not increase load time in android.

Comment: Surely that depends on your data characteristics and indexes in the Cassandra db?

Comment: @AndyBrown Thanks for the comment, every query script writer can't manage themselves from including "order by" in their queries from time to time, so that in my mind, I expressed myself freely with this idea ;)

Answer (score 1):

Given that the client platform is specified to be Android, I would sort it server side in order to reduce the performance cost for the client.

Comment: Android has nothing to do with it - hardware and size of data set/complexity of sort criteria does.